# Is it possible to define a required flag using System.Console.CmdArgs.Implicit?

Tags: haskell

Documentation clearly mention the use 'def', which provides a default value (empty) for the flag

```
sample = Sample{hello = def &= help "World argument" &= opt "world"}
         &= summary "Sample v1"
```

but I couldn't find a way to mention that I want to force the flag to be required.

Should I really go for Explicit or is there any way to define a required flag in Implicit?

Comment: Not really on topic, but I would also look at [optparse-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.5.2.1)--I have found it somewhat nicer to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation for [`opt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cmdargs/0.10.3/doc/html/System-Console-CmdArgs-Implicit.html#v:opt) states that

> Note that all flags in CmdArgs are optional, and if omitted will use their default value.

So it seems that it's not possible to define a flag as mandatory using the implicit style.

You can, however, detect the omission of a flag by using a `Maybe` value. E.g.

```
data Sample = Sample { hello :: Maybe String }
sample = Sample{hello = def &= help "World argument" &= opt "world"}
     &= summary "Sample v1"
```

Now if the flag is omitted, you get a `Nothing` and if the user provides a value, you get `Just "value"`. This means that you can check for `Nothing` yourself and terminate with an appropriate error message.

Comment: It is deliberate - console apps do not normally require named flags, although you can require positional arguments.

Comment: It makes totally sense. Didn't realize it immediately but now that you say it, it's obvious.